# Is there a current, 5e equivalent of Dungeon Magazine?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-insider

So, Dungeon got discontinued years ago, and it looks like D&D Insider isn't going to carry Dungeon style content.

Is there, or will there be, anything similar, in terms of **professionally written** short adventures, published singly or in collected format, for 5e?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is too localized in time to have current or lasting relevance without ongoing maintenance of both the question and its answer(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Dragon and Dungeon Magazine were not cancelled but put on hiatus**

> In years past, when we found ourselves at the lonely crossroads between game editions, the magazines simply went from one edition to the next with nary a breath in between. This time is different. As we turn our attention to the next D&D rules set, we’re putting Dragon and Dungeon on hiatus. The D&D magazines are going dark beginning in January. In other words, the December issues (#221 of Dungeon and #430 of Dragon) will be the last issues you see for a while. The magazines will continue on their present trajectories for the next few months, during which time we will answer questions such as the following: when will Dragon and Dungeon return, what form(s) will the magazines take, how much D&D content will the magazines publish, and how does one submit pitches for articles? As it stands, we have all the 4th Edition content we need to fill the remaining issues between now and the end of the year, and we are not ready to solicit content for D&D Next. Consequently, we are not accepting articles or adventure pitches this fall, and the submission window (which normally opens on October 1st and closes on November 30th) will remain closed. Anyone who sends a pitch to submissions@wizards.com will receive an automated “Thanks, but no thanks” response, along with a short explanation of why we’re not accepting content at this time. Every new edition is a chance for the magazines to
> evolve, and evolve they will. If you are interested in contributing to the D&D tabletop roleplaying game in the future, my best advice (for the time being) is to start up a regular D&D Next game and familiarize yourself with the new rules. Hone your writing skills
> as best you can. Then wait to see what happens next. - Chris Perkins. *Going Dark* [Dragon 427](http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dragon/427/Dragon427.pdf)

From this we can infer that Dragon and Dungeon magazine content or something along those lines will eventually come out again from WOTC. While the PHB is out, the full release of 5e has been staggered and across the months and 5e won't be "out" until both the DMG and the MM have hit shelves. This type of content may even be waiting for 5e's digital tools, [DungeonScape](https://web.archive.org/web/20210406144005/http://www.dnddungeonscape.com/), to be ready before they start being published.

Comment: I feel this answer should be updated to mention Dragon+. It's also outdated in that the books have released and DungeonScape has been replaced with Fantasy Grounds. I arrived here Googling Dragon+.